# How to think about adding HTML in MongoDB?

Tags: html, json, mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and JSON like data formats but I can see their combined potential in regards to being able to easily manipulate data with Javascript (jQuery) due to their similar syntax ie `"key": "value"` pairings.

There is a conceptual leap I am yet to make in regards to how I work with HTML content in this context, for example say I have a number of articles (with included HTML - `<p>`, `<li>`, `<img>` tags etc), how do I organise this content?

Do I add the HTML into Document 'content' values eg:

```
{ "title": "My First Article", "content": "<p>Welcome to this page</p><p>Today I would like to...</p><p>Etc <img src="cat.jpg"></p>
```

This seems counter intuitive and messy in terms of keeping the cleanliness of the JSON data that would be coming back to a web interface.  Plus it would make it difficult to 'read' the HTML in the Documents, as line spaces are not allowed etc.

What is this conceptual leap that I need to make in terms of how I think about adding HTML in MongoDB?

Comment: Short answer: don't. Save values and let HTML render itself.

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of how I go about letting HTML render itself?  I am guessing from your answer this means the database just stores the values without the markup, so how do I, for want of a better word, 'map' that data to relevant tags?

Comment: Something like this, I wrote it really conceptually mixing languages so it would drive the point home. http://pastebin.com/ePmBkzpU

Answer (score 1):

Your question we consider should be the following:

> *Do I have to modify HTML content I store?*

If you would need to insert, modify, remove elements with (for example) character data into, within, from the HTML **and** you need to do this differently on each request, the answer would be "maybe store it as a tree in MongoDB". But I'll just stick with "don't".

Every time you would want to print out your HTML as it is, you would need to construct the document, render as a string from the data stored in MongoDB. Also, you would need to parse and build the tree each time you wish to store it. It would be just a waste of resources and development time, just because your eye would like the view of an HTML document stored as a JSON tree.

Just start to implement it, and when you hear a shot, it will indicate a bullet in a leg.